# Search a string in a file and delete it from this file by Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to delete a line containing a specific string from the file. How can I do this without using `awk`? I tried to use `sed` but I could not achieve it.

Answer (score 72):

This should do it:

```
sed -e s/deletethis//g -i *
sed -e "s/deletethis//g" -i.backup *
sed -e "s/deletethis//g" -i .backup *
```

it will replace all occurrences of "deletethis" with "" (nothing) in all files (`*`), editing them in place.

In the second form the pattern can be edited a little safer, and it makes backups of any modified files, by suffixing them with ".backup".

The third form is the way some versions of `sed` like it. (e.g. Mac OS X)

`man sed` for more information.

Comment: I think it is usually a better idea to quote the expression and in addition I'd like to point out the `-i.bak` syntax where sed creates a backup file with the extension given. I.e. could be `-i.backup`, too ...

Comment: @STATUS you're right, some versions of sed actually need the suffix.

Comment: This does not work.This deletes string.I want to delete line that contains this string

Comment: It does work. It answers your question. You could use `grep -v` if you want to simply drop lines containing a certain string.

Comment: This is working in busibox, while `sed -i '/pattern/d'` does not (removes all the line, not the string)

Comment: Used this in `zsh` on Mac OS to get it to work I had to add double quotes but worked fine on entire directory: `sed -e "s/<br\/>//g" -i *`

Answer (score 36):

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' file
```

Use 'd' to delete a line. This works at least with GNU-Sed.

If your Sed doesn't have the option, to change a file in place, maybe you can use an intermediate file, to store the modification:

```
sed '/pattern/d' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Writing directly to the source doesn't work: `sed '/pattern/d' FILE > FILE` so make a copy before trying out, if you doubt it. The redirection to a new file FILE will open a new file FILE before reading from it, so reading from it will result in an empty input.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question. For safety reasons, you could use `-i.bak` instead of just `-i` to create a backup of your original file.

Comment: This is not working on busybox's `sed`, it removes all the line not the string, @mvds answer works

Comment: @danigosa: Well, that's why mvds answer is wrong, The question was, to remove a line, not the string. Read the question, read the comment of virtue in the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Didn't work on macOS. Had to do `sed 's/pattern//g'`

Comment: @pedromss: That's for deleting a word, not the line containing the word.

Comment: This seems to delete the line before the word too for me

Comment: @Freedo: Please note the different topic of headline and question text.

Comment: @pedromss, your code is good for test to print to stdout, but not to change the file if your os supports the use of the i flag.

Answer (score 2):

Try the vim-way:

```
ex -s +"g/foo/d" -cwq file.txt
```