# How to remove ^@ from text file in Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash, unix

I have output file generated from MSSQL table and i am trying to use it in Linux but it seems when i run export data from SQL Server it carries ^@ junk character and it causing issue while import, How we can remove ^@ from text file?

```
355|1|1|Build an Equipment Dashboard|build-equipment-dashboard|^@|Overview|asdf|
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584509/search-a-string-in-a-file-and-delete-it-from-this-file-by-shell-script) answer your question?

Comment: ^@ is probably a NULL value. You might be able to modify the query so that if a field is null you replace it with an empty string.

Comment: @aks : Also, for the safe side, verify what this character really is, by looking at the output with i.e. `xxd`.

Comment: How we can  check what are this character ?

Comment: Try `od -c filename`. Then please let us know what you find.

Comment: Okay @LeoSmith was correct, it is a NULL.

Comment: Try this: `sed -i 's/\x0//g' filename` - then run the `od` command again and see if it is gone.

Comment: Thanks sed command works, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '355|1|1|Build an Equipment Dashboard|build-equipment-dashboard|^@|Overview|asdf|' | sed -E 's/\^@//'
355|1|1|Build an Equipment Dashboard|build-equipment-dashboard||Overview|asdf|
```

see `man sed` ...
-E means extended regex. `^` must be escaped with `\` .

for a call on a textfile extend the `sed`-command with the `-i` option for inplace.

```
sed -Ei 's/\^@//' yourtextfile
```